# writing a replacement for a function which takes a variable number of parameters (c programming)

Tags: c, parameters, variadic-functions, printf

I'm looking to write a function to replace fprintf

```
int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
```

I'm not sure how to define a function such as this, because, after the format parameter, this function takes a variable number of parameters. Specifically, it takes at least as many additional arguments as were specified in the format.

**UPDATE** I found a resource on the subject (http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html), but the example doesn't seem to compile under Linux, the OS that I'm using.

An example of a replacement for fprintf which just calls fprintf would be helpful.

*This isn't homework. I'm just a beginner who is trying to learn how to program in his free time. Thanks!*

Comment: Why doesn't it compile?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: 14: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘args’

Comment: Lol, can you also post your code that throws that as well?

Comment: it's just the example given on the page I linked to in my post

Comment: Line 13 should be: int maxof(int n_args, ...) instead of int maxof(int n args, ...). The '_' seems to be missing in some places in the code. That's probably why is doesn't compile. Check all occurrences of 'n args' and make them 'n_args'.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of calling `fprintf` directly, you will need to call `vfprintf` instead. For example:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
int myfprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int r = vfprintf(stream, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return r;
}
```

In the standard library, every function that takes varargs (`...`) also has a `v` version of the same function that takes a `va_list` parameter. Since you can't construct arguments to pass to `...` dynamically, you need to use the `v` variant to pass on the varargs.